# Is today's date or time available in the default Django context in a template?

Tags: python, django

Is today's date or time available in the default Django context in a template?

I know that I could add a `context_processor` to make `django.utils.timezone.now` available globally in templates.

I am just wondering if it is already available?  And if so, what is the name / how do you access it?  That way I don't create something that is already there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to display the current date/time, you can use the [`{% now %}` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#now).